# Search using SOLR is not up to date

Tags: solr, solr4

I am writing an application in which I present search capabilities based on SOLR 4.
I am facing a strange behaviour: in case of massive indexing, search request doesnt always "sees" new indexed data. It seems like the index reader is not getting refreshed frequently, and only after I manually refresh the core from the Solr Core Admin window - the expected results will return...

I am indexing my data using `JsonUpdateRequestHandler`.

Is it a matter of configuration? do I need to configure Solr to reopen its index reader more frequently somehow?

Comment: are you performing commits which would make it available for search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to the index are not available until they are commited.

For SolrJ, do

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(host);
server.commit();
```

For XML either send in `<commit/>` or add *?commit=true* to the URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true`